# Make navigational bar transparent when reached anchor point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Im trying to make my navigational bar go transparent when it reaches an anchor point that I setup down the website.

Here is my Html

```
<div class = "nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <a href = "#index"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href = "#about"><li>About</li></a>
        <a href = "#><li>Logo</li></a>
        <a href = "#work"><li>Work</li></a>
        <a href = "#contact"><li>Contact</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.nav_bar {
            background-color: #ffc323;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80px;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 10;

}
```

This is the Jquery Code that I have so far but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var x = $("#about").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(".nar_bar").scrollTop() > x)
    {
        $(".nav_bar").css({"background-color":"none"});
    }
});
```

Im basically trying to reverse the nav bar of this website

http://dangblast.com

Is there a different method of doing this ?

Or am I getting closer to achieving the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

use RGBA for opacity:

> background-color:RGBA(1,1,1,0.1);

this should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
"opacity": "0"
```

It should work

Comment: k added the html and css. Hope that helps out